# How to get sheetnames, data from a specific cell in those different sheets and show 'listed' sheetnames, data and conditional logic in 3 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new here and trying to create an automated evaluation sheet.
See attached example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA0Uh.jpg)

Therefore I need to do the following:

- get the sheetnames in one column (if possible ascending).
- get the value in each sheet not the first two sheets!) of cell K43.
- write the data in the next column;
- create conditional logic as folows
- if value is between 0-7 > red background / white font;
- value is between 7-8 > white background / black font;
- value is between 8-9 > orange background / white font;
- value is between 9-10 > green background / black font.
- go to next column;
- if value is between 0-7 > show data from 'Informatie'!B2 & > red background / white font;
- value is between 7-8 > show data from 'Informatie'!B3 > white background / black font;
- value is between 8-9 > show data from 'Informatie'!B4 > orange background / white font;
- value is between 9-10 > show data from 'Informatie'!B5 > green background / black font.

I started like this:

```
function sheetnames() { 
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=2 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out
}
```

Thanks for your help.
Bruno.

Comment: You will not be able to set conditional formatting through a custom function, i.e. `=sheetnames()`.  It would need to be a script.

Comment: Or you simply set the conditional formatting through the menu.